# DNS Resolution with 2 A records

Tags: windows, dns, resolution, nslookup

So I'm a Windows / Network admin, have been for 2 years, but today I had a question that I didn't really know the answer to.

Say I do a nslookup, and the query retrieves 2 A records.

Which A records does say, a browser use?

If we do an nslookup for google.com, we get many responses. Is there a preferred address that windows uses? Is there any deciding factors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have three A records in example.com a,b,c

The first query will retrieve `a.example.com`

the second `b.example.com`

the third `c.example.com`, and the next will get `a.example.com` again.

This is known as [round-robin DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_DNS)